# Converting NSString to NSArray and storing in NSUserdefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I have a string that downloads from a server. It is in JSON format and is well-formed. It is an array of JSON objects. My objective is to convert this to an `NSArray` and then store it in `NSUserDefaults` for subsequent use. My attempt generally works, but sometimes I crash with this error:

> Attempt to set a non-property-list object

Here is the code that I am using. I think that it should be this straightforward. I don't believe have to actually convert the objects to `NSDictionaries` and iterate over this, do I?

```
NSString *message = [dict objectForKey:@"message"];
NSLog(@"message: %@", message);
data = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arr forKey:RESOURCES_LIST];
```

For example, this is one of the strings that causes this to crash (as output by the `NSLog` command):

> [{"folder":"Documents","files":[{"sort_order":"120","filename":"pdf.pdf","filetype":"pdf","display_name":"Instructions","upload_date":"2015-08-11","md5":"ea9f839f91941b5ea7f5a316e3ce95ca","bool_external":"0","url":"http://www.somesite.com/pdf.pdf"}]},{"folder":"Images","files":[{"sort_order":"100","filename":"space.jpg","filetype":"image","display_name":"example","upload_date":"2015-10-14","md5":"bc63b896949cbf87c54678fee8ed833b","bool_external":"0","url":"http://www.somesite.com/space.jpg"},{"sort_order":"110","filename":"profile.png","filetype":"image","display_name":"Profile","upload_date":"2015-10-14","md5":"740d61911560e1c84869563b83f3bbf8","bool_external":"0","url":"http://www.somesite.com/profile.jpeg"}]},{"folder":"Info","files":[{"sort_order":"130","filename":"info.pdf","filetype":"pdf","display_name":"info","upload_date":"2015-11-17","md5":"926a7941cc9c7f58e43c3eb2de661c27","bool_external":"0","url":null}]},{"folder":"Videos","files":[{"sort_order":"130","filename":"sample_video","filetype":"video","display_name":"Instructional
>   Video","upload_date":"2015-08-11","md5":"-1","bool_external":"0","url":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/PuNIwSsz7PI"}]}]

Comment: BTW - you shouldn't be storing data in `NSUserDefaults`. Once you solve the cause of this issue, you should write the array to a plist file instead.

Comment: OK. Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            "url": null
```

(in `[2][@"files"][0]`)
This is likely being parsed into a value of `[NSNull null]`, which cannot be stored in `NSUserDefaults`.  You will need to either change the server to send as an empty string or not at all, or (recursively) iterate and check all values, removing (or replacing with `@""`) all keys with value `[NSNull null]`.

For reference, the [acceptable classes in plist files and `NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html) are:

- Array (NSArray)
- Dictionary (NSDictionary)
- String (NSString)
- Data (NSData)
- Date (NSDate)
- Numerics [int32/64, float/double] (NSNumber)
- Boolean (NSNumber)

And keys must be strings.

Comment: That seems to be the problem. Thanks a lot!